# Django error: column does not exist but I have no control over that table?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have made a few changes in the code, but nothing that changes the model or adds new things to the database.
When I run on my computer it works fine, but when I try to build the docker image and run it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column c.relispartition does not exist
LINE 3:             CASE WHEN c.relispartition THEN 'p' WHEN c.relki...
                              ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 31, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 417, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 90, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 92, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 223, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    tables = self.connection.introspection.table_names(cursor)
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 52, in table_names
    return get_names(cursor)
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 47, in get_names
    return sorted(ti.name for ti in self.get_table_list(cursor)
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/introspection.py", line 49, in get_table_list
    cursor.execute("""
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/go/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column c.relispartition does not exist
LINE 3:             CASE WHEN c.relispartition THEN 'p' WHEN c.relki...
                              ^
```

For me this is strange because I have no control over what this table does.
When I run `makemigrations` and `migrate` it tells me that nothing has changed.

If I run the docker image against a local postgres database it works and there is no such error, this error is happening on production database.

I have tried the solutions to similar problems here on stackoverflow but nothing worked. It seems like the only solution is to create a new database...

Comment: What versions of Postgres are the local and production instances? The column `relispartition` does not exist before  Postgres 10.

Comment: Local is version 14 while production is version 9.6, that would be it thank you so much! Do you know why this problem only came up now? @AdrianKlaver

Comment: It's coming from `django/db/backends/utils.py` so have you upgraded Django recently?

Comment: That fixed it! While building the image que pipeline was grabbing a new version of Django, I've limited it to 3.2.7 and it worked. Thank you

Comment: What version was causing the issue? From the release notes 3.2.x versions are supposed to support Postgres 9.6+. If one is not you probably should file an issue here [Issues](https://code.djangoproject.com/).

Comment: It was using version 4.0, so no issues on their part ;)
Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks Magalhaes. I downgrade Django and it fixed.